# On macOS, after purchasing a non-consumable, at startup, my SKPaymentTransactionObserver always receives a .purchased transaction. Is this normal?

Tags: swift, cocoa, in-app-purchase

Thanks for your help. I am implementing in app purchase in my macOS application, and the implementation works well. A strange thing is that although Apple encourages to [persist](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/persisting_a_purchase) the purchase using another API, at startup, my SKPaymentTransactionObserver always receives a .purchased transactionState message, making the persisting implementation a bit pointless. Is this normal or am I missing something important and there is a problem in my implementation ? Thanks for your attention and for any help.

Comment: I am investigating, and it appears that this .purchased transactionState only takes place on Monterey (12.6, other versions not tested). On older systems, apart from persisting somehow the purchase record, it appears that a restore purchases is necessary.